Including Environment Specific Seed Data Scripts in Visual Studio SQL Database Project
I am m working on a Visual Studio SQL Database Project, and I have successfully imported my database schema. I can see it created dbo/Tables and Security folder automatically after importing the database.
However, I also have some environment specific SeedData scripts (for dev, sit, etc.) that I need to include. Where should I add these scripts?


Should I create a separate folder outside the SQL project (at the root of my solution) to organize these scripts?
Or is it better to add them within the SQL database project itself script?

I want to ensure that my GitHub action deployment process handles these seed data scripts correctly across different environments.
Any advice or best practices would be appreciated!

Regarding the two methods you mentioned for handling environment-specific SeedData scripts in a Visual Studio SQL Database project, here are some suggestions:

Create a folder named SeedData in the SQL database project, and create subfolders according to different environments, such as Dev, Sit, etc. The advantage of this is that all database-related files are managed in one project, which is convenient Maintenance and version control.
If your SeedData scripts are closely related to the database schema, but you do not want them mixed with the database project, you can create a separate folder in the root of the solution to store these scripts. This approach physically separates the script from the database project, potentially making it easier to manage environment-specific changes.

Whichever method you choose, make sure your GitHub Actions deployment process handles these seed data scripts correctly.
